# Navigate IE XML document from within VBA?

Tags: xml, vba, excel

I am trying to get lat/long values from Google's Map API.  I have no trouble creating the IE object in Excel and opening the browser but I'm having a heck of a time navigating the returned XML document to get the values I need.

I have created the HTMLDocument and the reference appears to be valid but I'm stumped how to navigate it.  Is there a way to obtain a string of the entire HTML output?  From that I can get what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Use MSXML - you need to reference Microsoft XML in Tools / References in the Excel VBA IDE.

You can load the XML from a file (`Load`) or a string (`LoadXML`). In my example I load from a file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<testxml>
    <tests>
        <test nr="1">Number 1</test>
        <test nr="2">Number 2</test>
        <test nr="3">Number 3</test>
        <test nr="4">Number 4</test>
    </tests>
</testxml>
```

VBA to load file:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestXML()
    '***** Declare document
    Dim oXmlDoc As DOMDocument
    Dim bRet As Boolean

    '***** Create empty document
    Set oXmlDoc = New DOMDocument

    '***** Load XML from file
    bRet = oXmlDoc.Load("c:\temp\test.xml")

    '***** Manipulate XML
    MsgBox oXmlDoc.Text
    MsgBox oXmlDoc.XML
    MsgBox oXmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//testxml/tests/test[@nr='3']").Text

    '***** Clean up
    Set oXmlDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```